# Bootstrapc3 : Overriding row left and right margins

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to override row class's default left and right margins which are

```
.row .row {
 margin-right: -15px;
 margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Page has multiple `rows` like
**HTML**

```
<div class="row row-padded" id="question1"></div>
<div class="row row-padded" id="question2"></div>
<div class="row row-padded" id="question3"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row-padded {
  margin-top:15px;
  padding-left:25px;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

It works fine if I overide it with `id`. This works fine for one row

```
#question1 {
 margin-left:0px;
 margin-right:0px;
}
```

but this does not

```
div[id^='question'] {
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It works both to me: http://jsbin.com/orafIco/1/edit

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3. Try with that please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand how specificity works. The reason that `div[id^='question']` doesn't override `.row .row` is because it only has one element and one attribute selector (considered the same specificity as a class) while the latter has two class selectors - classes override regular elements in specificity, so it makes sense that two classes combined has more priority than one class and one element. Also remember that an ID overrides both class and element selectors.

If you want the second selector to work, try:

```
div.row[id^='question'] {
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
.row{
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
}
</style>
```

Provide these codes in your page so that it will override default properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mark the margin properties as important:

```
div[id^='question'] {
    margin-left:0px !important;
    margin-right:0px !important;
}
```